# Avoiding killer croc bite in boss fight

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I'm really struggling with the first boss fight. I can manage to get killer croc down to one bar, but at that point I'm at half health just from the bite during the QTE.

I'm really struggling to avoid the three henchmen that pop-up. I always get hit in the middle of a block action by the croc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Boss fights are really annoying in that game. Try dodging instead of countering henchmen's attacks when fighting bosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're fighting wrong. What you should do is jump, jump, jump. And spam batarangs to the Croc.

Jump over/from henchmen and always have Croc on your screen to have time to jump away when he starts rushing towards you.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yup the second part of your answer was the key, always have Croc on my screen.